# mergeKEGGgraphs - error when merging multiple KEGG graphNEL objects

Tags: r, graph

There is a bug in the mergeKEGGgraphs function in the KEGGgraph R package. The code (below) produces the following error (also below). I have crawled the function's code, and have come to the conclusion (hopefully, a correct one), that this error is due to the lines directly below:

```
keggnodeing <- match(nodes(g), keggnodenames)
mergedkeggnode <- keggnodes[keggnodeing]
names(mergedkeggnode) <- sapply(mergedkeggnode, getName)
```

The error occurs because nodes(g) produces the Entry IDs (concatenated), of all graphs in the list of graphs that were merged using mergeGraphs at the beginning of the function mergeKEGGgraphs. However, keggnodenames produces the display names - not the entry IDs. So when you do a match(nodes(g), keggnodenames), you get null for all entries. There are no matches between entry ID and display names!

**Question: How can I get around this error so I can successfully merge these pathway graphs?**

Error message for below code:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘getName’ for signature ‘"NULL"’
```

Driver Script:

```
require(KEGGgraph)
require(KEGG.db)
require(XML)
require(RCurl)

tmp <- as.list(KEGGPATHNAME2ID)
j=1
kegg <- list()
names.kegg <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(tmp)) {
  file <- getKGMLurl(tmp[[i]], organism="hsa")
  xData <- getURL(file)
  if (xData!="\n") {
    doc <- xmlParse(xData)
    saveXML(doc, file=sprintf("hsa%s.xml", tmp[[i]]))
    kegg.pathway <- parseKGML2(sprintf("hsa%s.xml", tmp[[i]]))
    kegg[j] <- KEGGpathway2Graph(kegg.pathway,genesOnly=FALSE,expandGenes=FALSE)
    names.kegg[j] <- names(tmp[i])
    j<-j+1
  } else {
    print(sprintf("i = %d, hsa%s.xml no data", i, tmp[[i]]))
  }
}
names(kegg) <- names.kegg
kegg.merged <- mergeKEGGgraphs(kegg, edgemode = "directed")
```